# select/poll based framework in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I like to write an application that opens many sockets and files. Think of it as webserver (which is not true in my case, but to simplify the problem here).

If I would write it in C on Unix I would use poll/select and be quite efficient and because I don't have multiple threads, everything is easy to write, while being very efficient.

If I use multiple threads to use all cores of the CPU (given that I don't wanna use processes) I would use Unix FIFOs to transfer messages and use still poll/select on each thread (which works flawlessly with files/socket/fifos/). Things are still very simple while being quite efficient.

But when using C# it looks like there are different selects and most classes don't support that programming style at all (HttpWebListener just as one example). I don't like the `BeginInvoke` messiness because there are things happening in the background on which I don't have any control (ThreadPooling, Shutting down a blocking server gracefully, ...).

I wonder if there is any select/poll alike framework available for C#?

Comment: You might want to just stick to the facts instead of offensively expressing your opinion about asynchronous implementations.

Comment: @Dyapsyd Dyspayd - This question doesn't show - at least, I don't feel you are conveying it well - the type of research needed to ask an effective question.  Also, using verbage like "All this BeginInvoke shittery quite sucks" isn't a good way to get the community on SO behind you in your quest to get this idea off-the-ground.

Comment: Invoke/BeginInvoke is just SendMessage/PostMessage wrapping - it's not that worrying, honest, and you're going to be stuck with such messaging with any GUI.  If you're not using a GUI, you don't absolutely need it - there are other inter-thread comms mechanisms,  (eg. BlockingCollection), should you need them.

Comment: @Dyapsyd Dyspayd - It's easy to come to a language with preconceptions of how things **should** work. Your preconceptions are preventing you from making progress because you're tied to an idiom that seems somewhat old-fashioned. Why not embrace the new, particularly the async/await features introduced with C#5. It's really considerably easier than the route you seem determined to follow.

Comment: The problem is that nothing really seems to be thought out that well when I look at many of the existing APIs. It's just silly how the code locks, compared to a C version. I haven't tried out async/await yet and neither WCF. I used BlockingCollection but then the problem arises that I need even more threads go signalize each other and/or using locks. Things which I can so easily avoid with select/poll.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use your same approaches in C# - you just need to use the lower level [Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx), which provides [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx) and [Poll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.poll.aspx).

That being said, the new asynchronous methods built on top of socket in the higher level classes tend to have many advantages.  Once you learn and understand how they function, they can be very efficient and quite a bit nicer to develop against.

This extends all the way up the stack - with the "highest level" abstractions being frameworks like [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx), which provide huge benefits in terms of productivity, reliability, safety, and ease of development for many types of applications.

Comment: I've seen select/poll on sockets, but then files come, serial ports and so on. So there is no global select/poll functionality. Can I use WCF as well for communication between threads efficiently?

Comment: @DyapsydDyspayd You typically wouldn't use WCF for communication between threads - it's an entire architecture.  It can be used within a single application (be the host+client), but it's typically used for communication across processes.  Communication between threads (which really tends to be more a matter of synchronization between data used within threads) is typically handled other ways.

Answer (score 0):

BeginInvoke (or Tasks based on the Begin/End pattern) are the standard model of async programming on .NET. They indeed force the continuation callbacks to run on the thread-pool. If you are fine with that the Begin/End model is actually very efficient and nice (as nice as callback-based code can be...).

Of the top of my head I cannot see a compelling reason why I wouldn't want to use the thread-pool for completion callbacks. Maybe you can squeeze out a little more efficiency using IOCPs.

Select/poll certainly *isn't* the way to become more efficient. Although .NET sockets support it.

You said

> Shutting down a blocking server gracefully

would be a problem. I don't see why. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm more looking for the most elegant way. Using e.g. a Reactor pattern just as one another example. The problem lies within GetContext which I cannot nicely interrupt without generating Exceptions (this topic is discussed on SO as well). ThreadPooling means that Exceptions may happens in BackgroundThreads which I've to communicate forward and because there are even more threads involved anything must be ThreadSafe. I like to avoid the locks, like other language designers try to as well (Go, Scala, Erlang).